# Javascript Targeting Inside Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images...

```js
function leftMove(el) {
  if (el.className == "la") {
    el.className = "la1";
    getElementById(ra).className = "ra1";
  } else {
    el.className = "la";
    getElementById(ra1).className = "ra";
  }
}
```

```css
.la {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 370px;
  opacity: .5;
}
.ra {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 370px;
  left: 1637px;
  opacity: .5;
}
.la1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 370px;
  left: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.ra1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 370px;
  left: 1137px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="img.png" width="290" height="228" id="la" class="la" onclick="leftMove(this)">
<img src="img.png" width="290" height="228" id="ra" class="ra" onclick="rightMove(this)">
```

...that I am trying to modify. Specifically, I am trying to change the class of both images when either image is clicked. An example of the javascript I am using is:

The end goal would be to have both images reference new CSS, shown here:

If I do it correctly, both images should move and change opacity. For some reason, only the image with the "la"/"la1" class moves and changes opacity, while the "ra"/"ra1" image does nothing. I'm pretty sure this is because my javascript is broken, but I don't know why. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is the first code I've written, so please be gentle if I'm being obtuse.

Thanks for taking the time. :)

Comment: Just add " to your document.getElementById.. Like this: 
getElementById("ra1").className = "ra";

Comment: If you open developer tools, usually by pressing `F12` the console would have thrown an error pointing towards the issue.

Comment: The console says:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined"

This is the case even after getElementById is being passed a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a string to `getElementById` and call the function on `document`:

```
document.getElementById("ra").className = "ra1";
...
document.getElementById("ra1").className = "ra";
```

Comment: "ra" and "ra1" are now strings in my javascript, and I'm getting the same result. Did I mess two things up? :(

Comment: @Croog also call `getElementById` on `document`